# How to get aggregated list of logged error codes from MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

So, I have this table full of 10-minute data. In one of the columns is a system code, showing zeros for when there's no problem and any other number when there *is* a problem.

I'd like to generate a list of all error codes. Easy enough, of course, but here's the thing. I want to aggregate the data. Let's say that on January 28th at 17:10 an error occured which persisted until 17:40. Every seperate 10-minute entry between these two dates/times shows the same error code. How do I get a list which simply shows [errorcode][startdate][enddate] for each seperate occurence?

I've been looking all over the place, but haven't found a solution yet.

**Update**: Table structure

```
+-------+------------------+------+-------+--------+
|  Id   |       Time       | Wind | Power | System |
+-------+------------------+------+-------+--------+
| 44461 | 2012-01-28 16:50 |  0.3 |   0.0 |      0 |
| 44461 | 2012-01-28 17:00 |  3.3 |  10.1 |      0 |
| 44461 | 2012-01-28 17:10 |  4.4 |  53.7 |    275 |
| 44461 | 2012-01-28 17:20 |  4.7 |  -4.3 |    275 |
| 44461 | 2012-01-28 17:30 |  4.9 |  -3.9 |    275 |
| 44461 | 2012-01-28 17:40 |  5.2 |  -3.2 |    275 |
| 44461 | 2012-01-28 17:50 |  4.9 |  62.6 |      0 |
+-------+------------------+------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: please show your table structure

Comment: `select errorcode, min(date), max(date) from ... group by errorcode`

Comment: That doesn't quite work as errorcodes can occur multiple times.